# i got error like' Invalid descriptor index' while working with ResultSetMetadata

Tags: java, jdbc

```
package com.nt;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class DBResult {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    //genaral setting

        try{
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection         con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:oradsn","username","pass");
            Statement st=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select snum,sname,sadd from student");
            //here resultset
            ResultSetMetaData rm=rs.getMetaData();

            //get column count
            int cnt=rm.getColumnCount();
            //prints col name
            for(int i=0;i<=cnt;++i)
            {
                System.out.println(rm.getColumnLabel(i)+"\t\t\t");
            }//for
            System.out.println();

            //code to prints column value
            //System.out.println(rm.getColumnDisplaySize(i));
            while(rs.next())
            {
                for(int i=0;i<cnt;++i)
                {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(i)+"\t\t\t");
                }//for
                System.out.println();
            }//while

            //close jdbc conn
            rs.close();
            st.close();
            con.close();
            //class
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should check the code you submitted as example and remove the HTML tags .. also show exactly which error you are getting .. by highlighting where in the code you get this error

Answer (score 0):

`ResultSet` table index starting from `1` not from `0` so change your both `for loops` like this

```
for(int i=1;i<=cnt;++i)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: ya i got but the result is not as proper way,,

Comment: its because you'r using `println()` in the loop, use `print()`

Comment: yes i got now ,and here can we use buffer to store resultset values?

Comment: he ur write and how can we use buffer to save resultset data